# How to Pass a Function to Structure in C++?

Tags: c++, function, struct

My Struct Code :

```
struct MouseHandler
{
    void OnHover();
    void* OnLeftClick();
    // void (*OnLeftClick)();
    void OnRightClick();
    void OnDrag();
    void OnDrop();
};
```

Calling of Struct :

```
MouseHandler ms;
```

I am trying to pass **SampleScrollDownClickHandler** to **ms.OnRightClick()**, Is it is possible, How can I do that, I am tried this, but I failed :

`ms.OnRightClick() = SampleScrollDownClickHandler();`

**I am not using std library!**

Comment: `OnRightClick()` seems to return `void` so, no, you can't assign a handler to it like that. Please show a [mre].

Comment: You seem to want pointers to functions, which you have with the out-commented `OnLeftClick`.

Comment: `void (*OnRightClick)() = nullptr;` `ms.OnRightClick = &SampleScrollDownClickHandler;`

Comment: Thanks for All Answers Working Good, I can't Upvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the commented out line is actually closer to the solution you want.  In order to pass the function *pointer* you need to not call the function itself, which you did by invoking it with the trailing `()`.  So the following code is closer to what you want (limiting it just to the most basic parts of your code):

```
struct MouseHandler {
    void (*OnLeftClick)();
    void OnRightClick();
    void OnDrag();
    void OnDrop();
};

void my_callback() {
}

int main() {
    MouseHandler m;

    m.OnLeftClick = my_callback;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The member variables of the `struct` are not defined correctly.

`void OnHover();` declares a member function, not a member variable. You need to use `void (*onHover)();`, which can point to a non-member function.

```
struct MouseHandler
{
    void (*OnHover)();
    void (*OnLeftClick)();
    void (*OnRightClick)();
    void (*OnDrag)();
    void (*OnDrop)();
};
```

With that change, you can use:

```
MouseHandler me;
me.OnRightClick = SampleScrollDownClickHandler;
```

as long as `SampleScrollDownClickHandler` is declared and is the right function type.